# How to recover a mysql database(.MYD, .MYI, .frm) when the first character of the filename is a #

Tags: mysql, database

As written above, I have a Mysql-database stored as .MYD, .MYI and .frm -files, consisting of some tables. I have files like:

```
pavg.MYD
pavg.MYI
pavg.frm
...
#sql-75c_6ac1a.MYD
#sql-75c_6ac1a.MYI
#sql-75c_6ac1a.frm
```

When I copy all these files into the database dir, I only find the tables without '#'. What does the '#' in the tablenames do?

EDIT: I have still this problem. If anyone could give me some further advice I would be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Those file names refer to temporary tables created by mysql during queries, which are saved to disk, or [orphan innodb tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html) that are result of an alter table operation. Stricktly speaking, you should not need them for restoration operation.

Comment: But I think, these files contains the data i want to read. The readable tables got a size of about some MB`s, but the files beginning with '#' got round about 8GB....Is there a way I can read those files?

Comment: Pls read the documentation I linked. It describes a restoration procedure.

Comment: I didnt get it by reading the docu. Some more tipps would be nice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need to be a lot more specific in your feedback! Just saying that "I read it and I did not understand it" will not suffice. You need to describe what you have tried based on the description and what went wrong during the attempt to restore the data. Also, you specifically asked for explanation what table names starting with # stand for. You got that answer. If you need to know how to recover your database, you should ask that in a different question and probably not on SO, but on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok, I know that the data I need is inside the files I listed above(#sql-75c_6ac1a.MYD, #sql-75c_6ac1a.MYI, #sql-75c_6ac1a.frm).and i cant find a way to read this data. I read the docu, but I couldnt find a way to select the data inside the data. What do i have to do, to import these files like normal tables?